# For word pronunciation that have 2 consonants standing next to each other and at the end, Do we have to fully aspirate both of them?

Tags: pronunciation

I am confused about this question for long time but no internet resource explains about this.

Ok, when we have a consonant followed by an vowel in a pronunciation then for sure we have to fully aspirate the sound of that consonant. For example, in `has /hæz/`, we will fully aspirate `/z/`. That is meaningful. No problem right.

Now, when we have 2 consonants standing next to each other and at the end of a pronunciation, then my question is:

> Should we fully aspirate both of these 2 consonants?

For example, in `books /bʊks/`, should we fully aspirate `/k/` and then fully aspirate `/s/`. So, to pronounce `/bʊks/`, we will make 3 sounds:

-fully aspirate `/bʊ/`

-fully aspirate `/k/`

-fully aspirate `/s/`

Note: fully aspirate means fully pronounce (a sound) with an exhalation of breath. For example, when you fully aspirate `/k/`  (see video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhS65K59ogA, the lady made the `/k/` sound in the time of 0:24)

Or

> Should we fully aspirate the last consonant only and the before consonant should be in the starting position and your tongue will make the sound of the last consonant from that starting position?

For example, in `books /bʊks/`, when we finish the sound `/bʊk/` the back of the tongue will touch the soft palate and at that point of time we won't release the tongue to make the sound `/k/` but release the tongue to the `/s/` position to make the `/s/` sound.

I believe that if we make the sound like that then it will be different from when people won't put their tongue at the `/k/` position but after `/bʊ/` they will make `/s/` immediately and it will sound like `/bʊs/`

Ok, to make my question clearer, I recorded my voice so that you can imagine what I am asking about:

This voice shows the `/bʊks/` with aspirate of both  `/k/` and `/s/`. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLUHpmcnF2TFRCRTg/view?usp=sharing

This voice shows the `/bʊks/` with aspirate of `/s/` only. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLQVNMc0ZZSUhVaXM/view?usp=sharing

I think this is a very interesting question!

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re really asking here; your last two paragraphs are very difficult to understand clearly. Yes, you should pronounce both the /k/ and the /s/ in _books_; but the release of the /k/ is usually done with the tongue already in position for the /s/, so there is little audible release. I don’t understand what you mean by “fully pronounce /k/ which sounds like /kə/”, though: /k/ and /kə/ sound different in English (/s/ and /si/ even more so). You cannot just add a vowel at the end—that changes what the word is; e.g., [pʰaɪk] is _pike_, but [ˈpʰaɪkə] is _pica_.

Comment: No, we don't pronounce the penultimate consonent 'fully', if that's what you're asking. `Bones` isn't pronunced the same as `bonus`.

Comment: You really need to hear these words pronounced, say by BBC newsreaders.

Comment: @ Janus, I edited my question. I mean: 
 fully pronounce means you can hear the sound. For example, when you fully pronounce `/k/` it will sound like like `/kə/` (see video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhS65K59ogA, , the lady made the `/k/` sound in the time of 0:24)

Comment: @ Edwin,
Ok, to make my question clearer, I recorded my voice so that you can imagine what I am asking about:

This voice shows the /bʊks/ with pronounce of both  /k/ and /s/. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLUHpmcnF2TFRCRTg/view?usp=sharing

This voice shows the /bʊks/ with pronounce of /s/ only. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLQVNMc0ZZSUhVaXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This might help: http://www.forvo.com/word/books/#en

Comment: /k/ is aspirated at the beginning of words (like *king*), but it's not aspirated in *books* or *skin*. So it's not pronounced the ***same*** as at the beginning of the word. But it's still pronounced in that you can hear it.

Comment: @ everyone, i edited my question to make it clearer. So i use the word "aspirate" instead of "pronounce". To aspirate= pronounce (a sound) with an exhalation of breath.

Comment: If you listen closely to "book" being said in isolation, what you hear is "book-uh".  (It's just about impossible to not pronounce the "uh", so it's generally ignored.)  When the "k" is not at the end of the word you generally don't let that "uh" escape but go straight on to the following sound.

Comment: @user105551 I think you’re confusing two things here. In the video you linked to, the woman’s voice says [kʰə] three times first (not shown visually), and then you see her face move as she says [kʰ] _with no following vowel_. The aspiration is the _unvoiced_ breath that comes after the consonant (but only when it’s at the beginning of a syllable), and that doesn’t sound like [ə], which is _voiced_, a vowel. When you say _books_, there may be aspiration (though it generally merges with the following [s]), but there is _never_ a voiced [ə] section.

Comment: @Janus, in the video the picture aspirates /kə/ & the lady aspirates /k/. In my question, I mean the latter not the former. That is we make the /k/ sound likes the lady made

Comment: Also, aspiration normally refers to what is also known as _voice-onset time_, that is, the time that passes between the moment when a plosive is released (when the airflow that was cut off by the closure in the oral cavity is allowed to resume) and the moment when your vocal chords start vibrating to produce a voiced sound against. This concept does not apply to fricatives (in English, at least—certain languages do have aspirated fricatives) because fricatives are not released: the airflow is never stopped. So in _books_, the /s/ is never aspirated; only the /k/ **may** be aspirated.

Comment: @janus, i recored my real voice, so which one is your option? This voice shows the /bʊks/ with aspirate of both  /k/ and /s/. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLUHpmcnF2TFRCRTg/view?usp=sharing

This voice shows the /bʊks/ with aspirate of /s/ only. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLQVNMc0ZZSUhVaXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The gap between words is important here, even in fast speech. The transition between the k and s sounds is different in "The book said[that ....]" and "The books aid [understanding the subject ...]". (The vowel sound in "said" and "aid" is not quite the same of course but I can't think of an example followed by exactly the same vowel sound.)

Comment: @alephzero - However, a native speaker, not taking care to "enunciate" for someone who is perhaps not so "native", will run "book said" together to the extent that it's generally impossible to tell if it was "book said" or "books said".  Over the centuries English seems to have developed this ability to (mostly) tolerate words being run together, and neologisms are, in part, accepted or rejected based on their ability to "play well" with the rest of the language in this regard.

Comment: @alephzero “The book swayed” vs. “the books weighed” is a more exact example.

Comment: @HotLicks There’s little difference in rapid speech between _the book swayed_ and _the books swayed_; but there is an audible difference between both of those and _the books weighed_. That has to do with how long the sibilant /s/ is held: parallel to the distribution of aspiration, sibilants—and all other continuants—are held significantly longer in (stressed) syllable onset than in syllable coda.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - That's because "sw" in "swayed" is a different sound from "w" in "weighed".

Comment: @HotLicks No, not really. It’s because the _s_ in _boo[k sw]ayed_ is a different sound from the _s_ in _boo[ks w]eighed_. Obviously s is a different sound from w, but both phrases have the same phonemes in the same order; it is only the syllable boundary that separates them, just like the difference between _a nutter_ and _an utter_ is only the syllable boundary—both are phonemically /ənʌtəɹ/, but the first is /ə.nʌtəɹ/ and the second is /ən.ʌtəɹ/.

Comment: And if you can't express it in IPA it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit and the clarification the comments to the question have brought about, it is now much clearer what it is you’re asking here.

The simple answer is ***no***.

Generally speaking, plosives in English are mandatorily aspirated [pʰ tʰ kʰ] when they come at the start of a stressed syllable, or (usually) word-initially. In *all other cases*, they are usually non-aspirated [p t k], though they may sometimes optionally be aspirated for effect.

*Aspiration* here refers to a short period of time after the closure in the oral cavity that blocks the airflow is released, but before your vocal cords start vibrating to produce a voiced sound. During the aspiration phase, also known as the [*voice-onset time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice-onset_time), there is airflow, but no voice; you’re essentially pronouncing a [h]. When a /k/ comes at the start of a stressed syllable, the voice-onset time in English tends to be somewhere around 80 ms. Even in unaspirated plosives, your vocal cords don’t start vibrating *immediately*: unaspirated /k/ normally has a voice-onset time of about 15–20 ms in English.

In the example you give, *books*, the /k/ comes in the syllable coda, and as such is not normally aspirated. If you really want to emphasise that you’re saying *books* and not *boogs*, then you **can** aspirate the /k/ and say [bʊkʰs], but that is not very common, so use it sparingly.

However, the sound that follows /k/ here is a voiceless fricative and therefore by definition entails a continuous unvoiced airflow, just like regular aspiration does. The only difference is that in /s/, the unvoiced airflow is restricted by the position of the tongue against the roof of the mouth, with only a narrow hole the air can pass through.

When your tongue transitions from [k] to [s], the back of the tongue has to ‘let go’ of the soft palate, while the blade of the tongue in front has to ‘catch’ the alveolar ridge. These two movements are naturally difficult to time exactly, and it is very common that the first takes place perhaps 40–50 ms before the second. During that period, you do likely have some aspiration of the /k/; but it is not really noticeable, because it is shorter than the ‘full’ aspiration we find in *can* [kʰan] (perhaps half as long), and it tends to blend in with the sibilant airflow of the following /s/.

Comment: interesting answer. About your last paragraph, what if we don't aspirate the /k/ whatsoever (ie, we don't put the back of the tongue at the soft palate after /u/ in /bu/) and make the tongue immediately jump to /s/ position (ie, the front of the tongue catch the alveolar ridge to make the /s/ sound)? If that is the case, then it will sound like /bu s/. So then what is the difference between "/bu s/" & "/buks/ with /k/ not be fully aspirated"? very interesting question right?

Comment: That wouldn’t be not aspirating the /k/—that would just be leaving it out altogether, which would give an entirely different word. Actually, since [bʊs] isn’t a word (except in certain northern English dialects), it would in general give something that’s not a word at all. But if we take _bucks_ as an example instead and don’t put our tongue against the soft palate at all when pronouncing that, we would not be saying _bucks_ but simply _bus_. Some consonant clusters are frequently simplified, but final /Vks/ (V = any vowel) is not one of them; the /k/ must be pronounced.

Comment: This should probably go on the other posting, but it also seems relevant here: the aspiration becomes more obvious when one considers homophone(?) pairs like *face topping* and *faced hopping*, but probably not *face stopping* which should lack it. You can also play games with devoicing assimilation in related cases

Comment: I think there is a rule "if a stop followed by a consonant don't release the stop, but hold it", see my answer and give comment if you want to

Comment: This is really really interesting! Do you know of good book/article references or youtube videos that go into these details about how vowels and consonants are produced, how and in duration aspiration happens, etc. for someone new to this?

Answer (score 0):

First, leading consonants are not *always* sounded. Almost, but not always. For instance, the "h" in honor and honest is, except in Cockney, completely silent.

Second, there are several consonant combinations which are used to express sounds which are only faintly related to the components. "ng" is prounounced entirely at the back of the mouth, with none of the pressure at the tip of the tongue which is used in pronouncing a separate "n". "Pt", as in "apt" is pronounced as a single plosive, with no aspiration at all. Consider the difference between "apt" and "appetite". "Th" as in "breath" is also pronounced as a single sound, rather than anything like a sequence of different phonemes. Likewise with "nk" as in hunk. There are various others, as well.

If you are referring to trailing consonants which are added to existing words, particularly "s" and the d in "ed", the degree of unvoiced exhalation separating the two depends entirely on the mechanics of the sounds involved. In the case of books, for instance, the glottal stop which characterizes "k" makes it difficult to transition to "s" without a bridging exhalation. For "ts", on the other hand, as in "bets", all that is required to produces the "s" is to release pressure on the tip of the tongue. Since the tongue pressure blocked all exhalation, there is no unvoiced exhalation preceding the sibilant - any exhalation at all produces the "s".

Comment: I think that the Original Poster is using the terms vowel and consonant with their phonetic and phonemic sense, not the orthographic one. In that system there *is* no consonant at the beginning of the word *hour*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. So simple, that is the rule of stop consonant.

> if a stop followed by a consonant don't release the stop, but hold it

See this video at time of 19:53
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPvmjom0hwY&index=3&list=PLTx3GskMNoe-RRIzJpBKscBJEZk8E9zzZ

Comment: That woman doesn't know what she's talking about—or she's oversimplifying. She's conflating release and aspiration of plosives, at any rate. The rule she gives here is true of _homorganic_ consonants, but not heterorganic ones. In _pop music_, the p is not released, but in_pop song_ or _pop list_ it is. It is not aspirated, but it is released. Also note that she aspirates the final p in _pop_ when she says it in isolation, which is misleading: that is only done when you wish to emphasise the sound, not in normal speech.

Comment: she is very famous, she got 20 years of teaching pronunciation

Comment: I believe she is right cos her theory is simpler but no other source from internet discuss about this

Comment: In that case, she’s presumably simplifying things for her students. Or alternatively, just because she teaches pronunciation doesn’t mean she’s a phonetician. The rule as she gives it here is **not correct**. Stop are not automatically unreleased before any other consonant. Also whether a theory is simple or not is not relevant to whether it’s correct or not.

Comment: but i feel it is much easier for me to speak a word, for example, "books" by holding the /k/ and release the /s/. Applying that rules for "pop music" , "job market", "had this",... I feel it very natural. If i have to fully release all these stop consonants (the ones before other consonant) then my speaking is a bit of clumsy and hard and somewhat unnatural

Comment: what kind of accent do you have?. Maybe that lady uses the rule of American Accent

Comment: I think you are mishearing yourself. Technically speaking, the /p/ in _pop music_ is also released, just not orally. When saying /p/, the airflow is cut off in two places: at the lips (by pushing them together) and in the back of the mouth (by raising the velum to the back of the pharynx). When you release /p/ normally, you open the constriction both places, and the pressure of the built up airflow is what causes a ‘pop’, the sound of the release (with or without aspiration). When you say _pop music_, you release the pharyngeal constriction, but not the labial one. →

Comment: → There is still built up air pressure that makes a small ‘popping’ noise when the constriction is released, but it’s at the back of your closed mouth and therefore less noticeable. When you say _books_, the opposite happens: the velar restriction (tongue against velum) is released, but the pharyngeal one is maintained. But it is in fact _very difficult_ not to release the /k/ at all: that requires closing both tongue-velum and velum-pharynx, stopping your vocal cords and airflow, releasing _both_ constrictions _without_ any airflow, putting the blade of your tongue against the alveolar →

Comment: → ridge, and only _then_ starting the airflow again. That is much, much harder to do. (This holds true not only for American English, but for all other dialects of English as well, and indeed for most languages in the world, even ones where final stops are normally unreleased, like Vietnamese, which I'm guessing is your native language.)

Comment: I think your theory and her theory is almost the same. The only difference is that she made it simple while you provide a greater details. But in your answer you DID NOT say "most languages in the world, even ones where final stops are normally unreleased". So you admitted by chance she is somehow right